# creating .jar file with package

Tags: java, netbeans

I have created a simple .jar file with an interface definition and two classes. I then add the to the netbeans project. All the classes are shown in the default package in the .jar when browsing using the netbeans gui. However, inside the netbeans project, I can't use any of the classes defined in the .jar file. When I try to use it, it says cannot find symbol.

Here is how I create the jar file:

```
javac Funizor.java RequestStatus.java DrugInformation.java
```

then

```
jar cvf furnizor.jar Furnizor.class RequestStatus.class DrugInformation.class
```

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message?

Comment: When using in another class file in the project, netbeans is saying cannot find symbol.

Comment: Can you post the output of `jar -tvf furnizor.jar` and show us the code that is complaining? Guessing that you have some packages?